# SELECT FOR UPDATE in hsqldb using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

When I run a query on hsqldb (1.8.0.7) in mem mode  using hibernate (4.2.3.Final)
I get the following exception

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: FOR in statement [SELECT *
 FROM MYTABLE where ID=? FOR UPDATE NOWAIT]     at
 org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)    at
 org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)   at
 org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)    at 
 ...
```

does hsqldb support select from update?

Answer (score 1):

In the [updatability](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_jdbc_cursor_updatability) section of the documentation for 2.3 states that it is somehow supported:

> If the SQL qualifier, FOR UPDATE is used, then all the updatable
>   columns of the result set become updatable.

But I haven't been able to find it in the doc for 1.8. I found some sites, like [this](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/hsql.html), saying that SELECT FOR UPDATE is not supported in version 1.8.

> No concurrent migration support (to make Flyway cluster-safe) with
>   Hsql 1.8, as this version does not property support SELECT ... FOR
>   UPDATE locking

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT FOR UPDATE` is fixed in HSQLDB 2.3.3.

However NOWAIT will be fixed as noted [HSQLDB 2.3.3 NOWAIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32128450/2103767)