# Does HSQLDB support FOR UPDATE?

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB v2.3.3 with Hibernate v4.3.9.Final. I want to verify if the FOR UPDATE works in the query. My query is as follows:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Building.lockBuildingByIdForUpdate", query = "SELECT b.* FROM building b WHERE b.id = :buildingId FOR UPDATE", resultClass = Building.class),
})
```

My Java code is as follows:

```
    public Object createNew( String buildingId ) {

      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss,SSS" );

      System.out.println( format.format( System.currentTimeMillis() ) + ", Before acquiring lock..." + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", buildingId=" + buildingId );
      buildingDao.lockBuildingsById(buildingId);
      System.out.println( format.format( System.currentTimeMillis() ) + " After acquiring lock..." + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", buildingId=" + buildingId );

      //Some further Save data in the Database logic which I am omitting on purpose
}
```

I have written a test case that spawns two thread as follows:

```
executor.execute( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println( "First Thread Started..." + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", buildingId=" + buildingId );
            Object job = getService().createNew( buildingId );
            System.out.println( "First Thread Ended..." + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", buildingId=" + buildingId );
        }
    } );

    executor.execute( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println( "Second Thread Started..." + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", buildingId=" + buildingId );
            Object job = getService().createNew( buildingId );
            System.out.println( "Second Thread Ended..." + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ", buildingId=" + buildingId );
        }
    } );
```

My expectation is that whichever thread acquires the lock must be the only one who goes ahead and completes the transaction. And then only the second thread must go ahead with its own execution.

However, this is not what I see. I see that both the thread acquire the lock almost simultaneously. My output is as follows:

```
First Thread Started...pool-7-thread-1, buildingId=bldg_id_1
Second Thread Started...pool-7-thread-2, buildingId=bldg_id_1
2017-11-29 03:49:34,527, Before acquiring lock...pool-7-thread-2, buildingId=bldg_id_1
2017-11-29 03:49:34,527, Before acquiring lock...pool-7-thread-1, buildingId=bldg_id_1
2017-11-29 03:49:34,594 After acquiring lock...pool-7-thread-1, buildingId=bldg_id_1
2017-11-29 03:49:34,594 Retrieving SomeObject pool-7-thread-1, buildingId=bldg_id_1
2017-11-29 03:49:34,598 After acquiring lock...pool-7-thread-2, buildingId=bldg_id_1
2017-11-29 03:49:34,598 Retrieving SomeObject pool-7-thread-2, buildingId=bldg_id_1
2017-11-29 03:49:34,674 Got SomeObject pool-7-thread-2, buildingId=bldg_id_1
2017-11-29 03:49:34,674 Got SomeObject pool-7-thread-1, buildingId=bldg_id_1
2017-11-29 03:49:34,711 Saved  newJob in DB pool-7-thread-2, buildingId=bldg_id_1
2017-11-29 03:49:34,711 Saved  newJob in DB pool-7-thread-1, buildingId=bldg_id_1
Second Thread Ended...pool-7-thread-2, buildingId=bldg_id_1
First Thread Ended...pool-7-thread-1, buildingId=bldg_id_1
```

So the output clearly shows that the lock is not applied and both the threads are able to acquire the same lock.

My question: Does HSQLDB v2.3.3 supports FOR UPDATE? I read it on internet [[SELECT FOR UPDATE in hsqldb using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052406/select-for-update-in-hsqldb-using-hibernate]) that it does. By experience is different.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32207496/330315) int the linked question contains a link to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126332/hsqldb-oracle-mode-select-for-update-nowait/32128450#32128450) which states: "*Version 2.3.3 of HSQLDB does NOT support NOWAIT.*"

Comment: Did you remember to turn auto-commit off? A lock only lasts until the end of the transaction, so without transaction management, `for update` is fairly meaningless.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but I am using only FOR UPDATE without NOWAIT. Are they same?

Comment: @Andreas, my auto commit is ON

Comment: Auto-commit = lock released as soon as statement returns, i.e. before `After acquiring` prints. You got the lock, then threw it away.